# JOptionPane Descending order Array *almost there*

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, user-interface, joptionpane

So i've been grinding at this for a while now. I have got to the point where I am able to type in how many arrays I have, and input each individual array. However, once it gets to the sorted part, it just constantly repeats the initial response of how many arrays I have. For example, If I typed in that I have 3 Arrays, it will do it's thing and let me enter 3 different Arrays. However, when it comes time to it being sorted in Descending order...it doesn't do that. Instead it will just individually show my initial choice of 3 Arrays as well as the number 3 (three times). Also, how can I get my final result to show in one single GUI in a horizontal fashion?

```
package one;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class one {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String response;
    response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number of elements: ");
    int numberOfElements = Integer.parseInt(response);

    int[] values = new int[numberOfElements];

    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfElements; index++) {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Element " + index + ": ");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(response);
        values[index] = value;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numberOfElements; j++) {
            if (values[i] < values[j]) {
                int temp = values[i];
                values[i] = values[j];
                values[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorted:");
    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfElements; index++) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, +values[index]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You’re ignoring the response from the JOptionPane inside the first loop and are simply using the first response gained from the user

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the return result from `showInputDialog` in your first loop and continue to use the original `response` value used to create the number of elements

```
for (int index = 0; index < numberOfElements; index++) {
    response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Element " + index + ": ");
    int value = Integer.parseInt(response);
    values[index] = value;
}
```